# Should I use the native angular-material or a Bootstrap-like material design framework instead?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

Besides the fact that Angular Material uses flexbox, is there a programmatic (speed, etc.) benefit to using a material design framework that is native to Angular versus using a Bootstrap-like framework such as Materialize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Angular Material Design** project contains lots of directives that you won't have to write. So yes, there is a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

Please keep in mind, that angular-material doesn't support old browsers.